# Populating a table with PDO PHP

Tags: php, pdo

I'm trying to populate a table with data from a database with no luck in PDO. I'm new to PHP so I have search around and yet to found solution. The table is not populated at all, no data. Here is my code.

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM actividades");
$stmt->execute();

echo "<table id=\"premiacionguaynabo\"> <tr> <th> No. </th> <th> Fecha </th> <th> Torneo </th> <th> Lugar </th> <th> Organizador </th> <th> Opciones </th> </tr>"; //The table and the headers are created  

$tno = 0;

$result = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($result as $line) {
    $tno = $tno + 1;
    $id = $line["idactividades"];
    print "<tr class=\"alt2\">"; 

    print "<td id=\"idtorneo\">  $tno  </td>";
    print "<td class=\"fechatorneo\"> " . $line['fecha_inicial'] . " al " . $line['fecha_final'] .  "</td>";
    print "<td> <a id=\"plinks\"  href=\"$picture\" rel=\"lightbox\" target=\"_top\" title=\"Flyer del Torneo\"> " . $line['ntorneo'] . " </a></td>";
    print "<td>" . $line['ltorneo'] . "</td>"; 
    print "<td>" . $line['otorneo'] . "</td>"; 

    print "<td id=\"idtorneo\"> <a id=\"udlinks\"  href=\"uactividades.php?idactividades=$id\">  Edit  </a>   <a id=\"udlinks\" onclick=\"return confirmDelete()\"  href=\"dactividades.php?idactividades=$id\">  Delete  </a></td>";
    print "</tr>"; 
}

print "</table>";
```

Here is how I connect to my DB

```
      $dbhost = 'myhost';
$dbname = 'dbname';
$dbuser = 'myuser';
$dbpass = 'mypass'; 


try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname;", $dbuser, $dbpass);

     }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo $e->getMessage();

    }
```

Comment: what is the problem????

Comment: The table is not populated at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try change

```
foreach($result as $sline) {
```

to

```
foreach($result as $line) {
```

That's not the problem in that case, but change

```
$result = $stmt->fetchall();
```

to

```
$result = $stmt->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

since you use column names to get values.

Comment: do `var_dump($result);` right after `$result = $stmt->fetchall();` and make sure that you have your resultset populated.

Comment: you also need to change `$id = $sline["idactividades"];` please try to debug first since your problem is very obvious you are not using variable which have that data

Comment: Still can't populate the table

Comment: You are again using `$sline` in `foreach`, but trying to access array members with `$line`.

Comment: `foreach($result as $line)`

Comment: Sorry in the computer I had it corrected but not here in the page. Still not work with the correction.

Comment: It doesn't output anything

Comment: That's your problem. Your query either fails or your table is empty. BTW post you code when you create $dbh object (i.e. connect to your db).

Comment: I have seem to load the table, but it I delete a record it will not load the table again. Since this is a different problem I will post another question and Mark your answer as the correct one. Thanks.